# How to include a php file in php with condition

Tags: php

While running my code on localhost I had a problem with the `include` command.

Here's my code:

```
<?php
 $res = 2; // this also can be change to any number. it is based on user input, but for simply the problem i make it to be set manually
 If ($res =1,){

    $open = include ("weekend.php");
}
else{
    $open = include ("weekday.php");
}
echo $open;
?>
```

I expected the output to be `weekday.php`, but the output is `weekend.php`.
It works fine if I use `$res = 1`.

Comment: correct your if condition.........
If ($res =1) changes into **if ($res == 1)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides the obvious typos (the capital I in `If`, the comma at the end of the condition), you're using the wrong operator. `=` is the assignment operator. In order to check equality, you should use the `==` operator:

```
if ($res == 1) {
    // ---^
    $open = include ("weekend.php");
}
else {
    $open = include ("weekday.php");
}
```